# Pass Jquery Data to print.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two page, the index.html and print.html

on my index.html page there is a calculator and i have a button called print that is located on index.html
when you click PRINT button, it would go to print.html. My problem is does not send the input value I made on index.html. 
Note:  This work if I dont go to print.html. the value shows up,   but if set it on another page, the value does show up

**PRINT.HTML**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#print_modal').click(function() {
     e.preventDefault();   


var rec_product = $('#rec_product').val();
var calc_height = $('#calc_height').val();
var calc_width = $('#calc_width').val();
var calc_depth = $('#calc_depth').val();


$('#srec_product').text(rec_product);
$('#sheight').text(calc_height);
$('#swidth').text(calc_width);  
$('#sdepth').text(calc_depth);  

        window.print();
        return false;
        window.location.href = "print.html";
        window.open(url, '_blank');   


     });
```

Comment: return false; <<< nothing after this will be executed, If it would then 
        window.location.href = "print.html"; <<< nothing after this would be executed - so not this: 
        window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: rewrited. What I want is to call the input value from index.html to print.html using jquery

Comment: You mean `"print.html?val="+value` and use location.search in print.html?

Comment: i want to send the input value from index.html to print.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location = '/print.html?rec_product='+$("#rec_product").val()+'&calc_height='+$("#calc_height").val();
```

for loading your print.html in same window tab.

If you are sending multiple parameter use following code to get value on print.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
load();

function load()
{
     window.location.search.replace ( "?", "" ).split("&")
         .forEach(function (item) {
        var tmp = item.split("=");
        document.getElementById(""+tmp[0]).value=tmp[1]; 
     });
}

</script>
```

If you want to do it via jquery then use

```
$("#"+tmp[0]).val(tmp[1]);
```

insted of:

```
document.getElementById(""+tmp[0]).value=tmp[1];
```

You must have same name input type fields as send in parameter.

You can also use load function code in your

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

on print.html.

Comment: As suggested in my comment

Comment: how would i cal rec_product so it would display on the print html?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#print_modal").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = //get input value
        $.get( "print.html", {"value":value});
    });
```

this jQuery code will direct you to `print.html?value=12`(where 12 is your value).

You can then use PHP in print.html to retrieve the value (`$_GET['value']`)

Comment: if it has extension .html it is likely not php - anyway that is what I suggested in my comment